# How to reset primeng datepick calender

Tags: angular7, primeng, angular8

I am trying to reset primeng datepick calender but not working.I am working in angular 8.I have created custom datepicker component using primeng.I have given my code below.How to reset that?Anyone can have idea?please help to find the solution.

app.component.html:

```
<p-calendar dateformat="mm/dd/yyyy" [numberofmonths]="4" selectionmode="range" formControlName="datePick"></p-calendar>

<button (click)="resetdate()">Reset Date</button>
```

app.component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('p-calendar') calendar: any;

resetdate(){
this.calendar.value = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using reactive forms, in the reactive form it will set with form control setValue method.

**Update**: You can provide model value as an array.

component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
<p>
    Date Reset
</p>
<p-calendar formControlName="date" selectionMode="range" [readonlyInput]="true"></p-calendar>
<button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
<button (click)="setCustomDateRange()">Set Custom Date Range</button>

</div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl , FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  yearRange = '2000:2020';
  myGroup: any;
  rangeDates: Date[];
  constructor(){
    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
    date: new FormControl('')
  });
  }
  setCustomDateRange(){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 10);
    this.myGroup.get('date').setValue([new Date(), date]);
  }
  reset(){
    console.log(this.myGroup.get('date').value)
    this.myGroup.get('date').setValue(null);
  }


}
```

check [working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rsztgh)

Comment: How to set value for date range?

Answer (score 1):

Use `[(ngModel)]` as below:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value"></p-calendar>
```

and in ts use:

```
 value: Date;

  resetdate() {
    this.value = null;
  }
```

**[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-ng-calendar-vmxprf?file=app/calendar/calendar.component.ts)**

Comment: Can you use formControlName?

Comment: If i use like this not working: <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" formControlName="datePick"></p-calendar>

Answer (score 0):

If necessary, like for me, you can destroy and recreate the component like this :

```
<p-calendar *ngIf="showCalendar"></p-calendar>
<button (click)="resetdate()">Reset Date</button>
```

`detectChanges()` method apply `*ngIf` and destroy the component:

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

showCalendar = true;

resetdate(): void {
  this.showCalendar = false;
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  this.showCalendar = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to create separate method to reset data binding on module. just use property **showClear="true"** on tag

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" [showClear]="true"></p-calendar>
```

for reference check [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/calendar)